# how to start asp.net mvc 4 ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

plaese guide me to start asp.net mvc 4 ajax enabled multi platform web application. I have a REST service hostrd in another domain, want to consume it. please guide me whether i need to access that service from javascript ajax call or
create models at server and request my server with ajax call. any guides links much appreaciated..
regards
ani

Comment: I need a startup, please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact way to consume your web service will depend on the content of this service, and how you want the user to interact, but, from my point of view, the server should be interacting with the webservice, and your user with your server. That is, as you guessed, "models" should reflect your web service data structure.

If you want to use ajax, use it to call methods in your controller(s) to load/update data from the webservice.

It's a bit difficult for me to go further without knowing what we are talking about, but to give you a better idea of what I am talking about, I wrote my own "API" to deal with Amazon Products Advertising API, using their rest service instead of SOAP. This same API is being used by 3 differents web applications.

Inside each web application there are AJAX calls to controller methods, who in turn calls my API methods.

This mechanism works perfectly in this case, but it may not in yours, which is why I believe you need to tell us a little more about hte kind of service and application you are going to build.

Sorry to stay a little vague, still hope this helps.

Bernard